# Unity - no java runtime present requesting install

Tags: java, macos, unity-game-engine

I used Unity Hub to install Android build tools. I can locate these files on my computer. I set JAVA_HOME and "java -version" command works fine. When I try to build I get following error: No Java runtime present, requesting install. what can I do?

Unity Version: 2019.4.9f1.

Mac OS Catalina

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm2Rq.png)

Comment: when you use 'java -version' does it shows you your JRE version?

Comment: this is the result:
openjdk version "1.8.0-adoptopenjdk"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-adoptopenjdk-jenkins_2018_05_19_02_01-b00)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b00, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and installed JDK manually and finally it worked

Comment: Please provide link from where you downloaded and if any other changes you've made